# Accessing a COSArray for PDF fields with Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, pdfbox

I'm trying to access all form fields in a PDF file - so I can use code to fill them in - and this is as far as I've gotten:

```
PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdf.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();

List<PDField> fieldList = pdAcroForm.getFields(); // fieldList.size() = 1

PDField field = fieldList.get(0);

COSDictionary dictionary = field.getCOSObject();
System.out.println("dictionary size = " + dictionary.size());

// my attempt to iterate through fields
for ( Map.Entry<COSName,COSBase> entry : dictionary.entrySet() )
{
    COSName key = entry.getKey();
    COSBase val = entry.getValue();

    if ( val instanceof COSArray )
    {
        System.out.println("COSArray size = " + ((COSArray)val).size());
    }
    System.out.println("key = " + key);
    System.out.println("val = " + val);
}
```

which gives an output of:

```
dictionary size = 3
COSArray size = 2
key = COSName{Kids}
val = COSArray{[COSObject{110, 0}, COSObject{108, 0}]}
key = COSName{T}
val = COSString{form1[0]}
key = COSName{V}
val = COSString{}
```

Does anyone know how I can access the two COSObjects in the COSArray? I also don't know what the notation COSObject{x, y} means, and can't find any documentation on this.  If those are dictionary or array values elements, I also want to know how to access those.

Comment: While @Tilman's answer correctly explains how to dereference the objects in the array, I think that instead of using `pdAcroForm.getFields()` you should simply use `pdAcroForm.getFieldTree()` or  `pdAcroForm.getFieldIterator()` which return you all fields directly.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try getFieldTree() and it ran for several minutes without finishing...but I suppose there's nothing I can do about that.  It's a pretty complex PDF form.

Comment: makes me wonder if there is some sort of endless loop. Please share that file if you can (preferably on the PDFBox user mailing list; upload to a sharehoster because attachments are deleted)  https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/

Comment: Indeed, that sounds like an endless loop. Which in turn would be caused by a flaw in the pdf. If you shared it, we could inspect it. Then the field tree code can be hardened against such effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the object with `get(index)` to get the `COSObject` (an indirect reference) or `getObject(index)` to get the dereferenced object referenced by the `COSObject`.

`COSObject{110, 0}` is the object number and the generation number (usually 0). Open your PDF file with NOTEPAD++ and look for "110 0 obj" to find it, or "110 0 R" to see who references this object.